# Traefik not routing to static resources within a docker backend

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

Traefik is unable to route client-side scripts that request static resources to the right back-end. As such, static resources like JS, CSS, Images fail to load.

In a nutshell, I am attempting to set-up traefik to act as an internal (within a LAN) reverse proxy using PathPrefixStrip to access multiple applications on a single host, e.g.

http://{IP-ADDR}/AppA
http://{IP-ADDR}/AppB

Sadly, it has been an uphill struggle to get it to work consistently.

Everything works as expected when:
- Setting up Traefik dashboard / whoami for PathPrefix
- Configuring the front-end rule to allow access at site root (e.g. http://{IA-ADDR}/ )

The following screenshots provide the level down configuration:

[Accessing Calibre-web directly - http://{IP-ADDR}:8083](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHABX.png)

[Acessing through traefik - http://{IP-ADDR}/books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QJjg.png)

[Traefik Access Logs - Highlights indicate back-end can not be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw6Kr.png)

[Docker compose file for Calibre-web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugOMK.png)

[Traefik Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dDOH.png)

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!
M

Comment: any answer u got??